# Why I cannot create my own analogue of Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

I've grabbed the source code of Nullable<T> class from the https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ and put it to the file and renamed to NullableZZ (and also the sources of NonVersionableAttribute into separate file).
When I've tried to build the next code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NullableZZ<int> n1 = 100;
    NullableZZ<int> n2 = null;
}
```

I've got this error:

> Error  CS0037  Cannot convert null to 'NullableZZ' because it is a non-nullable value type    ConsoleApp2 C:\Users\Roman2\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs

Why the C# compiler does not want to compile it? Has it some "tricks" to compile its "own" version of Nullable<T>?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why the C# compiler does not want to compile it?

Because it doesn't have any specific knowledge of your class, but it *does* have specific knowledge of `Nullable<T>`.

> Has it some "tricks" to compile its "own" version of `Nullable<T>`?

Yes. The `null` literal is convertible to `Nullable<T>` for any non-nullable value type `T`, and also to any reference type. It is *not* convertible to `NullableZZ<int>`. Also, `int?` is effectively shorthand for `Nullable<int>` - it has special treatment.

Basically look through the specification (e.g. the [ECMA C# 5 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)) and observe everywhere that it talks about `Nullable<T>`. You'll find *lots* of places that it's mentioned.

Nullable value types have support in the framework, the language and the CLR:

- The `Nullable<T>` type has to exist in the framework
- The language has support as described in this answer
- The CLR has support in terms of validating generic constraints and also boxing (where the null value of a nullable value type boxes to a null reference)